# fancyhdr package not found

Tags: installing, fancyhdr

I'm trying to use the `fancyhdr` package for headers and footnotes for my LaTeX report, but when I compile TeX returns an error saying that `fancyhdr.sty` file can't be found.

Any suggestion on how to proceed please?

Comment: Also, note that it'll be really easier for people to help you if you provide your code, together with a direct copy of the error message.

Comment: to double check type `kpsewhich fancyhdr.sty` at the command line terminal to see its path. please update your Tex distro. For Texlive `tlmgr update -all -self` or for miktex install `fancyhdr` package

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can download fancyhdr here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/

To install it simply drop the sty file into either the location your packages are stored in or in the same folder as the document you're currently working on. Both should work.

If you tell us your OS and what Latex version you use, we might be able to also give you a way to install these more automatically.

Comment: ```yum install texlive``` solved this for me on fedora. I had only installed latexmk which was insufficient.