# Fancy Header Sty Not found

Tags: fancyhdr

I updated my TeXShop for Macbook along with downloading the latex Tex Package (MacBook 2022 - March) off Tug.org, however, templates I created before won't run "fancy hdr. sty not found.  I looked up where to drop the file (sty) in my directory, but it still doesn't work.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The space between fancy and hdr is strange. The package name is `fancyhdr`.

Comment: That is the error in the log file. I know the package has no space.

Comment: But the space in the log file should not be there.  Its existence suggests you had a space in your source file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download the fancyhrd package from Ctan. I ran each of the recommended files (dtx, ins), those ran without problem and then I found the folder where all the latex packages are housed and dropped the files in.

Worked perfectly.

Comment: That suggests you had a deficient installation, and that you'll run into more problems with other packages.

Comment: I think you are right. I had fancyhdr prior to this installation (March 2022) and my files worked and I ran into trouble when I was trying to edit them this year. I found a post from 2013 that lead me in the right direction https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89871/fancyhdr-package-not-found